# Excel Index Match Last Record

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

there are dynamic fields defined in the list, and I want to get the last element of the matching field. how can I do it?

such as,

[image]

If I want to get "0.49" value, I use this formula.

=INDEX(DailyRate!B:B,MATCH("Sunday",DailyRate!$A:$A,FALSE)+2,1)

But, what should I do if I want to get "0,94"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nest some INDEX/MATCH:

```
=INDEX(INDEX(B:B,MATCH(D3,A:A,0)+1):B$1000,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(INDEX(B:B,MATCH(D3,A:A,0)+1):B$1000="",),0)-1)
```

[image]